# grep does not take pattern from file

Tags: linux, grep

I have a pattern file, say *t.txt*, containing the following:

```
vali
```

and the file I want to run grep against, say *a*, containing the following:

```
validate
validate:

bw_validate:
 [echo] Validating project: CrossService_v1_59_5_1
 [echo] Found 62 errors and 28 warnings
 [echo] -----------------------------------------------------------------
 [echo] Validating project: CRM-UDB_59_4_2
 [echo] Found 25 errors and 28 warnings
 [echo] -----------------------------------------------------------------
 [echo] Validation Failed: At least one project contains errors.

notify:

BUILD FAILED
bw.xml:311: Validation Failed: At least one project contains errors.
```

if I execute:

```
grep -iE vali a
```

I get the expected output, i.e.:

```
validate
validate:
bw_validate:
 [echo] Validating project: CrossService_v1_59_5_1
 [echo] Validating project: CRM-UDB_59_4_2
 [echo] Validation Failed: At least one project contains errors.
bw.xml:311: Validation Failed: At least one project contains errors.
```

but if I execute:

```
grep -iE -f t.txt a
```

I don't get any match.
files are readable and both in the same directory (from which I execute the command).
I tried both with -f and --file=t.txt, --file='t.txt', --file="t.txt"

I'm on linux Fedora 16 64bit. Strangely enough, the same command works properly in windows with the grep/egrep porting.

Am I missing something? 
Any help is appreciated as this is giving me an headache :(
thanks!

Comment: Can you please do `cat -vet t.txt`. Looks like your pattern file may contains some `spaces` or `special characters` in them.

Comment: You are right, it showed some extra ^M right before the end of the line. converting it with dos2unix solved it.

Comment: Cool, I have posted an answer just for reference incase if you ever happen to work on a system that does not have `dos2unix` available. Good luck!!

Comment: I was also having problems with DOS newlines, it wasn't failing but was only matching against the final line of the pattern file. The command worked properly after I ran dos2unix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should work right (it works for me). The `-f` switch is specified by POSIX.

The fact that you say it's working on Windows gave me an idea: Could it be the `t.txt` file ends with a DOS newline? I tried it with a clean file (no newline), and it worked. Then I tried it with a DOS file, and I was able to reproduce your results.

Try `dos2unix` to "fix" DOS files.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the `dos2unix` utility then you can do any of the following to convert DOS or Windows newlines to Unix newlines.

1. This one-liner assumes that all lines end with `CR+LF` (carriage return + line feed)

   ```
   sed -i 's/.$//' filename
   ```
2. You can usually enter the `^M` control char literally on the command line by first pressing `Ctrl-v` (control key + v key) and then `Ctrl-m`.
   ￼￼￼￼
       sed -i 's/^M$//' filename
3. This following one-liner assumes that we are using GNU [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed). The hex value for CR is 0x0D.

   ```
   sed -i 's/\x0D$//' filename
   ```